# IN can be used with multi-part keys by using the struct constructor syntax?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know the meaning of the following syntax, taken from  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#in-operators

```
(Key1, Key2) IN ( (12,34), (56,78) )
(Key1, Key2) IN ( SELECT (table.a, table.b) FROM table )
```

Meaning is display the rows when key1 has the value 12 or 34 and key2 has the value 56 or 78. Am I correct? If not simple example would be useful to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 12 key1, 13 key2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 12, 34 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, 57 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 56, 78
)
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (key1 = 12 AND key2 = 34)
OR (key1 = 56 AND key2 = 78)
```

Now you can re-write it as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 12 key1, 13 key2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 12, 34 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, 57 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 56, 78
)
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE (key1, key2) IN ((12,34),(56,78))
```

which makes it (depends on user's preferences) more readable

in both cases output is

```
Row id  key1    key2     
1   2   12      34   
2   4   56      78
```

the syntax `(key1, key2)` combines those two values into one [`STRUCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct-type) and then compares with another STRUCTs - `(12,34)` and `(56,78)`

Same with second example

```
(Key1, Key2) IN ( SELECT (table.a, table.b) FROM table )
```

where qualified structs are "taken" from select statement vs. constants as it is in first example

Comment: easy to understand thanks, i got another doubt, is it possible to use 'for' statement in bigquery?

Comment: clarify what you mean please